# Obtaining the Russian Typewriter keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, big-sur, internationalization, language, switching

This is my very first experience with Apple products. For the last 20+ years, I have been using the *Russian Typewriter* keyboard layout that is available out-of-the-box in all Windows and GNU/Linux distributions.

(This layout is much more convenient than other Russian layouts, as the digits are typed via <kbd>Shift</kbd>, while <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> are available when you press <kbd>6</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> without <kbd>Shift</kbd>. In many other Russian layouts, the comma and the dot are under the right pinky, and sometimes even on the same button, so that you need to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> to type a comma.)

I have tried to find the *Russian Typewriter* keyboard layout in <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> > <kbd>Input Sources</kbd>. In the list of available Russian layouts, there are only three options:

- Russian
- Russian - PC
- Russian - Phonetic

Is that possible to find the *Russian Typewriter* keyboard layout in the settings? Or my only option is to utilise an external application, such as Ukelele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not provide a Russian Typewriter layout, so you have to get it online or make one yourself with Ukelele.

One source for this is via the [Keyman](https://help.keyman.com/keyboard/russian_type/1.0/russian_type) app.

Comment: Installing custom software to only bring new keyboard layout into system - insane...

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install the Russian Typewriter layout from here: http://www.lintest.ru/wiki/MacOS

1. Download provided zip file.
2. Extract two files: `Russian (Typewriter).icns` and `Russian (Typewriter).keylayout`.
3. Put them to the `$HOME/Library/Keyboard Layouts` directory.
4. Change the layout in the `Keyboard` preferences.